# Web pages are not auto reloading after applying changes

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, ktor

I'm using Intellj Idea with kotlin and ktor framework to develop a web site.

I have enabled the development mode and I'm watching the directories but the page does not reload when I make changes on the project

```
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0", module = Application::module, watchPaths = listOf("resources","classes"))
        .start(wait = true)
}
```

I have added this variable to the IDE configs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeA4J.png

And I'm watching the directories, even the console tell me that the program is already watching the directories and is waiting for changes. When I make a change nothing happens, the pages I'm working on don't not reload.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Do you recompile the project after a change?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Yes

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please check that the listed directories for watching contain the recompiled class files.

Comment: Is not generating the new compiled files, I need to stop the program and manually execute it again to generate the new version of the app.